# Choosing a linear model to take into account multiple observations from the same individuals

Tags: r, mixed-model, repeated-measures, linear-model, multilevel-analysis

I’m looking at how temperature varies across age. Can you help me to choose the most appropriate linear model to this analysis?

I’ve got multiple measures from 1 individual per age (13 in total), and in two cases only (11yo and 15yo) I've got 2 pieces of data from 2 individuals. This's an example of how my dataset looks like:

```
  temperature  id   age  
1      20       A     15
2      22       A     15 
3      21       D     15
4      20       B     10
5      19       B     10
6      19       C     9
```

I could calculate the mean and use a univariate test but what if I want to take into account the multiple observations per individual?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mixed model is not indicated here, because you have only 3 individuals, so we would be asking the software to estimate a variance for a normally distributed variable (since random effects are assumed to be normally distributed) from only 3 observations of it.

A more appropriate model would be:

```
temperature ~ age + id
```

This will take account of the multiple measures within `id`

Edit: Gordon is right - see comment below - this approach will not work. id and age are collinear so you can't put them in the same model and instead you will need to take the average temperature for each id

Comment: Age is entirely confounded with id, so it is impossible to estimate an age effect from this model. IMO OP needs instead to average the temp for each individual.

Comment: @GordonSmyth quite right. I hadn't noticed that !

Comment: Thanks Robert and @GordonSmyth for your answers! In my question I should mention that the dataset is just an example. The individuals I'm taking into consideration are 13. But I've got multiple observations from 1 individual only per age. Only in the case of 11yo and 15 yo I've got some data from 2 individuals.

Comment: Ahh OK. So perhaps you can include the output of  `summary(mydata)` and `str(mydata)`. Just edit the question and put 3 backtickes (```) in front and after the text and the system will format it nicely.

Answer (score 3):

I would do it in two steps. First a oneway anova to check whether there are any significant differences between the individuals at all:

```
fit <- lm(temperate ~ id)
anova(fit)
```

If the anova is not significant then the differences between individuals are no larger than measurement to measurement variation on the same individual, so there is no point in proceeding further.

If the anova is significant, then compute average temperature per individual and perform a linear regression to explore whether the between-individual differences can be explained by age.

Comment: After we compute the average temps, is there no benefit to using the information that individuals had different numbers of observations? My intuition tells me that we should give more "weight" to the data for individuals with more observations.

Comment: @JoeMansley In practice, no. The variance of the average temperature is not inversely proportional to the number of observations because the observations for an individual are not independent, rather they all share the same random effect for that individual. The variance does decrease slightly with the number of observations but quickly asymptotes and the rate of decrease depends on the relative size of the variance components, which itself is unknown.

Comment: @JoeMansley Theoretically a linear mixed model analysis can use all the observations without averaging but (i) the gain in power is very slight, (ii) the analysis is very much more complex and (iii) mixed model analyses make their own approximations and require larger sample sizes to be reliable.